# Reverse DNS gives: no such host is known

Tags: c#, .net, dns

```
using System;
using System.Net;
    class MySocket
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string IpAddressString = string.Empty;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an IP address (e.g., 131.247.2.211):");
            IpAddressString  = Console.ReadLine();
            IPAddress hostIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(IpAddressString);
            IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostIPAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("\nHost name of: {0} is: {1}", hostIPAddress, hostInfo.HostName);
        }
    }
```

I enter an IP address and then I get the following:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host
>   is known    at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(IPAddress
>   address, Boolean includeIPv6)    at
>   System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress address)    at
>   MySocketLab.Main()

This is an example of my input:

```
gethostname.exe
Enter an IP address (e.g., 131.247.2.211):
208.27.32.23
```

This looks correct from online sources. IS there something else I need to do?

Comment: Could you please provide your inputs as well ?

Comment: Does it throw you this exception for any IP you enter? If yes, I assume that this is a security/permissions issue. Anyway, I suggest you using the following NuGet package: http://dnsclient.michaco.net  -- as it gives you the option you choose your own DNS server and not to depend on your operating system.

Comment: @Yan correct. This is for every IP I try. I used Microsoft's as an example because I knew it would have a hostname to return.

Comment: Interesting, when i try `172.217.169.142`(google) i get no errors but when i try your input `208.27.32.23` i get an error as well. Also, when i ping your input `208.27.32.23` i get no response as well.

Comment: @CemYILMAZ ping means nothing in terms of ptr. @Jason, I don't get any records for `208.27.32.23` neither. try `216.58.198.229` for example, what do you get? Also, open `CMD` in windows, and put the following nslookup command: `nslookup -type=ptr 208.27.32.23` - what is the result?

Comment: `dig -x 208.27.32.23 +short` shows no result, so this IP address has no PTR records and hence no name resolved for it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59770306/c-sharp-dns-gethostentry-exception-no-such-host-is-known