# C# Dns.GetHostEntry() - exception: No such host is known

Tags: c#, windows, networking, dns

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=netframework-4.8) **Dns.GetHostEntry() Resolves a host name or IP address to an IPHostEntry instance**. Could anyone help me understand why this function doesn't work for some external IP address (it works for internal IP address) and the ping command works normally?

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a host name or IP address");
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: ConsoleApplication1 8.8.8.8");
                return 1;
            }

            string addr = args[0];

            try
            {
                IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);
                Console.WriteLine($"GetHostEntry({addr}) returns HostName: {host.HostName}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e);
            }

            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>ping stackoverflow.com
    
Pinging stackoverflow.com [151.101.1.69] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 151.101.1.69: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=57
Reply from 151.101.1.69: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=57
Reply from 151.101.1.69: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=57
Reply from 151.101.1.69: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=57

Ping statistics for 151.101.1.69:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 35ms, Average = 20ms

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>ConsoleApplication1.exe 151.101.1.69
Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByAddress(IPAddress address, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>ping 151.101.1.69

Pinging 151.101.1.69 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 151.101.1.69: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=57
Reply from 151.101.1.69: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=57
Reply from 151.101.1.69: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=57
Reply from 151.101.1.69: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=57

Ping statistics for 151.101.1.69:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 27ms, Average = 19ms
```

I found a solution changing the file

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Adding the line:

```
151.101.1.69 stackoverflow.com
```

It works after this change

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>ConsoleApplication1.exe 151.101.1.69
GetHostEntry(151.101.1.69) returns HostName: stackoverflow.com
```

In my opinion, changing hosts file is not a good solution to solve this issue. Does anyone know a better solution to solve this?

Comment: You can't solve this as it works as intended. If the DNS server has no entry/label for the IP address it can't give you a result. If you do `tracert 151.101.1.69` or `tracert stackoverflow.com` on the command line you will see that not every IP address (151.101.1.69 included) has a DNS label. Even though stackoverflow.com was resolved to 151.101.1.69, the backward resolving from IP to DNS name doesn't work as their seems to be no record for this direction. Resolution from DNS -> IP is done using the A records, but from IP -> DNS is done using the PTR records.

Comment: @ckuri I don't want to solve the DNS. I already have the IP address. I don't want the exception

Comment: TryParse the input as an ip address first. If it isn't an ip address, try DNS lookup.

Comment: @HungRuoHan You want a reverse DNS lookup. All I am saying is that this is only possible for certain IPs (where the DNS server is configured appropiately) and if there is no result you will get an exception as this is intended behaviour.

Comment: Thank you @John. I was expecting get a better understanding about Dns.GetHostEntry() behavior, but it is ok i will add an extra protection calling TryParse(). Thank you for your time

Comment: Do you try with the `Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostNameOrAddress)` method?